# How to create my own .inc include file for my assembly modules? I'm using nasm

Tags: assembly, include, nasm

For homework for my CA course I am required to make a `.inc` include file for the assembly modules I've written. The problem is I don't know how, and I haven't been able to find anything about it with google.

So basically I have this `IONUM.asm` file with multiple functions I would like to call from that other `MAIN.asm` file I have. For this I must use a `.inc` file. I cannot just simply write `%include 'IONUM.asm'` as I'd like but rather `%include 'IONUM.inc'`.

What should this file contain that tells the program making the call where to find said functions? I know it has to look something like this

```
%ifndef __IONUM_INC__
%define __IONUM_INC__
extern io_readint
extern io_writeint
%endif
```

What else does it have to contain? How do I set the path for those functions? Should I include it like `nlink MAIN.obj -lIONUM -o test.exe`?

Comment: Have you tried what you have?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart What do you mean? Yes, I've tried just that and it won't  compile. Should that really be enough? In that case I'll try again.